# How can we get each `data-id` when I click on `dateFrom` and `dateTo` datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can we get each `data-id` when I click on `dateFrom` and `dateTo` datepicker (jQuery ui datepicker).

I have to pass each `data-id` to server when I click on `dateFrom` and `dateTo` datepicker.

Currently I am getting only first value data-id="5799f281049ac12422000033"

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000033">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000034">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row calendar" data-id="5799f281049ac12422000035">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom hasDatepicker" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" placeholder="Arrival" readonly="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control dateTo hasDatepicker" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" placeholder="Departure" readonly="">
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
            var data_id = $('.calendar').data("id");
            $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/availability,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data: { dateFrom: start_date, data_id : data_id  },
                    success: function (response) {
                        array = response.disableDates;
                    }
                });
            } 
            });

            $( ".dateTo" ).datepicker({ datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.y",
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/availability,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data: { dateFrom: start_date, data_id : data_id  },
                    success: function (response) {
                        array = response.disableDates;
                    }
                });
            }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onChangeMonthYear`, get the `data-id` of the immediate `.calendar` ancestor using the `closest()` method of the clicked datepicker, which can be referenced through `this`.

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst) {

    var data_id = $(this).closest('.calendar').data("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/availability,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: { dateFrom: start_date, data_id : data_id  },
        success: function (response) {
            array = response.disableDates;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside onchange function,

```
 var id = $(this).parent().parent().data("id");
```